Number of integer solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$ with ranges $x_1\geq 0, 4\leq x_2\leq 7, 2\leq x_3\leq 6, x_4\geq 0$
Number of integer solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$  with ranges $x_1\geq 0, 4\leq x_2\leq 7, 2\leq x_3\leq 6, x_4\geq 0$
I tried the method by @N. F. Taussig: Number of integer solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 28$ with ranges
My attempt:
The question reduces to $x_1'+x_2'+x_3'+x_4'=24$ where $x_1'=x_1\geq 0$, $0\leq x_2'=x_2-4\leq 3$, $0\leq x_3'=x_3-2\leq 4$, $x_4'=x_4\geq 0$
Let $3-x_2'=y_2$, $4-x_3'=y_3$ given
$x_1'-y_2-y_3+x_4'=17$, $x_i',y_i\geq 0$.
How to proceed further.
Edited my question

See this answer
for a blueprint of how to combine Inclusion-Exclusion with Stars-And-Bars to
attack this generic type of problem.

A key difference between this problem and the one to which you linked is that in the linked problem all of the variables have upper bounds.  Therefore, I was able to avoid using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle by introducing the $z$ variables.  In this case, only two of the four variables are bounded, so applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (or using generating functions together with the negative binomial theorem, which amounts to doing the same thing with fancier machinery) becomes necessary.

You may consider proceeding directly from
$x_1'+x_2'+x_3'+x_4'=24$ over non -negative integers s.t. $x_2'\leq 3, x_4' \leq 4$ and just apply the familiar stars and bars with PIE to get
$$\small{\binom{27}3 - \binom{23}3 -\binom{22}3 + \binom{18}3 = 430}$$

Here's another method. Introduce $x_2 = 2+a$ and $x_3=4+b$ to shift to start from $0$ and iterate over all allowed $a,b$. The number of solutions when $a$ and $b$ are given values is equal to the number of solutions of $x_1+x_4 = 24-a-b$, which is given by the usual stars and bars. We get
$$
\sum_{a=0}^3 \sum_{b=0}^4 \binom{24-a-b+2-1}{1}
= 25 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 - 5\cdot \frac{3 \cdot 4}{2} - 4\cdot \frac{4 \cdot 5}{2}
= 430
$$
Summing was easy because we we're left with just two variables. If there were more, we'd get higher power sums and need to use those formulas (and foiling the binomial coefficient would also be kind of messy).

No solutions possible.
The largest the sum $x_2 + x_3$ is 13.  Adding $x_1$, as required cannot obtain 30.
It is worse for smaller sums of  $x_2 + x_3$.

Once the problem has been edited/fixed:
Mathematica:
Solve[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 30 
      \[And] (x1 > -1) 
      \[And] (4 <= x2 <= 7) 
      \[And] (2 <= x3 <= 6) 
      \[And] (x4 >= 0), {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers] // Length

430

? I thought that $x_1$ could be any positive number, so $x_1=17$ should surely yield a solution, don't you think? (I admit that writing $\le$ for $x_2$ and $x_3$ and $\ge$ for $x_1$ is confusing indeed.

@DavidG.Stork Edited. $x_1 \geq 0$. Solution is possible: $x_1=23, x_2=3,x_3=3, x_4=1$

$x_2=4, \space  x_3=6$ and $x_1+x_4=20$ give many solutions.
